# 'Using a for loop to compare if each element of an ArrayList equals a user response

Tags: java, arraylist

I have already figured out how to do it using a different method but apparently I must use a for loop, I feel like i'm using the wrong syntax or something but I have googled and searched for close to an hour now so I have no idea how to fix this seemingly easy problem.

Here is what I think is the relevant part of the code:

```
public static void deleteEntry()
    {
        response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to REMOVE it from the list");

        for(int i=0;i<birdList.size();i++)
        {
            if(birdList(i).equals(response)) **//this line is giving me an error. birdList has a red line under it in eclipse.**
            {
                birdList.remove(response);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
            }
            else if(i == birdList.size())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
            }
        }

        /* How I was originally going to do it before I re-read the requirements.
        /*if(birdList.contains(response))
        {
            birdList.remove(response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
        }
        else
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
        }*/
```

Here is all the code:
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class BirdArrayList {

    static ArrayList<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>(5); 
    static String response;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        birdList.add("Crow");  //adding fice initial birds to the birdList ArrayList
        birdList.add("Magpie");
        birdList.add("Dove");
        birdList.add("Finch");
        birdList.add("Kookaburra");


        while (response != "5")
        {
            response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the number for what you wish to do \n"
                    + " 1 \t ADD a bird to the list \n"
                    + " 2 \t REMOVE a bird from the list \n"
                    + " 3 \t SEARCH for a bird in the list \n"
                    + " 4 \t DISPLAY the list of birds \n"
                    + " 5 \t QUIT the program"); // Main screen of the program, formatted nicely

            if(response.equals("1")) // Add a bird
            {
                addEntry();
            }

            if(response.equals("2"))//Remove a bird from the list
            {
                deleteEntry();
            }

            if(response.equals("3"))//Search for a bird
            {
                //searchEntry();
            }


            if(response.equals("4"))  // Displays the array
            {
                displayArray();
            }
            if(response.equals("5")) // Quit the program
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void addEntry()
    {
        response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to ADD it to the list"); 
        birdList.add(response); // adds the response to the birdList in the next Array position
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " added!"); // Shows bird name added
         displayArray();
    }

    public static void deleteEntry()
    {
        response =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a bird name to REMOVE it from the list");

        for(int i=0;i<birdList.size();i++)
        {
            if(birdList(i).equals(response))
            {
                birdList.remove(response);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
            }
            else if(i == birdList.size())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
            }
        }

        /* How I was originally going to do it before I re-read the requirements.
        /*if(birdList.contains(response))
        {
            birdList.remove(response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, response + " removed!");
        }
        else
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The bird you tried to remove was not on the list");
        }*/
    }
    public static void displayArray()
    {
        String displayList = "";
        int tempCounter = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<birdList.size();i++) //Display the ArrayList 
        {
            String tempBird = birdList.get(i); //Makes tempBird more workable in the displayList formula 2 lines down
            tempCounter++; // shows a nuber before the bird in the list
            displayList += tempCounter + ".   " + tempBird + "\n";   //formatting nicely    
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayList); //Displays the list

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer finally on reddit it should have been

```
if(birdList.get(i).equals(response))
```

instead of

```
if(birdList(i).equals(response))
```

Thanks for all the other answers lads.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (response != "5")
```

You should not compare String with == or != as it compares if two objects are the same while you want to compare their equality.
Use rather the `equals(Object o)` method.

Besides, you should place first the `"5"` before in the comparison to avoid a `NullPointerException` if `response` is `null` :

```
   while (!"5".equals(response))
```

At last, you don't handle the `null` case in the while.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will look into fixing this now, any ideas about the question asked in the OP

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, you have the List::removeIf method.

```
birdList.removeIf(bird -> bird.equals(response));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I must use a for loop to do the removal. I have been looking for ages now and its really annoying because I already have working code it just doesnt use  for loop.

Comment: Can I ask you why the for loop? Out of curiosity

Comment: Purely because its a proof of understanding for my teacher. I feel I have an understanding for for loops but cant seem to get the syntax right for this particular one.